# Server 2008 R2 VPN clients are unable to ping netbios names

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, cisco-asa

I just setup the VPN yesterday. Our current setup:
Internet> asa5505 (setup with the NAT rules ect to forward traffic to the VPN server)> Server 2008 R2 server> network.

We have multiple DCs and AD systems. The ASA5505 is the DHCP server.

People connect correctly via VPN and they can ping IP addresses and FQDNs (system.domain.local) but they are unable to ping the UNC name. (system name). 
Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

NetBIOS is not (supposed to be) a routable protocol.  You can technically create an IP helper on your router to forward NetBIOS traffic, but this is not advised as you are causing NetBIOS to behave in a way that it was not designed to.

That is why WINS was created -- as a naming service for NetBIOS.  But please do not start using WINS. It's legacy tech.

Try altering the DNS Suffix Search order on your clients if you want to be able to ping by single-label name.

Comment: I would agree with the netbios/WINS. 

earlier i changed the DNS suffix to only include the primary Domain controllers IP address (manual edit of the connection).

Comment: When I ping the server name it pings correctly but wont allow me to ping any other system names

Comment: When I ping server.domain.local it pings correctly I mean. But when I ping server it does not.